# How to see the fact that $\zeta_{p^2}$ is a root of $x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+...+x^{2p}+x^p+1$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I have seen a proposition: $\zeta_{p^2}$ is a root of $x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+...+x^{2p}+x^p$, and $x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+...+x^{2p}+x^p+1$ is the mininal polynomial of $\zeta_{p^2}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

But so far, by a simple substitution, I am not able to find a way to rearrange the equation and get zero, so could someone please help? May I please ask for a step-by-step deduction which leads to $0$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please explain the symbols. min po;y must have a non-zero constant term

Comment: @SoumikGhosh Oh sorry I forgot that there is a "1". Edited. The $\zeta_{p^2}$ is the $p^2$-th root of the unit.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is to apply the algebraic identity $$y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}+\cdots+y^2+y+1=\frac{y^p-1}{y-1}$$ valid for every $y\ne1$, to $$y=(\zeta_{p^2})^p$$ and to note that, by definition of $\zeta_{p^2}$ as a $p^2$th root of unity, $$y^p=1$$ hence the RHS of the identity is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to compute $\Phi_{p^2}(X)$. We have $\zeta_{p^2}$ is a root of $\Phi_{p^2}(X)$ by definition. Now we have $X^{p^2}-1$=$\Phi_{p^2}(X)$$\Phi_{p}(X)$$\Phi_{1}(X)$. We know $\Phi_{1}(X)=X-1$ and $\Phi_{p}(X)=\frac{(X^p-1)}{X-1}$. Thus we get $\Phi_{p^2}(X)=\frac{X^{p^2}-1}{X^p-1}$ which is exactly the polynomial you wrote.

we know $\zeta_{p^2}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p^2}}$. So $f(X)=\frac{X^{p^2}-1}{X^p-1}$ we have $f(\zeta_{p^2})=\frac{e^{2\pi i}-1}{e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}-1}=0$

Comment: Sorry I have not seen the $\Phi$ before. May I please ask if it is possible to simply substitute $\zeta_{p^2}$ into the polynomial and use some relation to see the fact that it is indeed a root? Other than finding a proof-based method to find its minimal polynomial.